# How do I compute ∞/∞ correctly in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I had tried the code below in Mathematica 8:

```
f[z_] := (5 + 1/(z-a)) / ( 8 + 1/(z-a))

f[a]
```

and surprisingly I got following warnings:

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered. >
```

and the output is `Indeterminate`, which I think is not true because obviously it's `1`.

What's weird is that when I changed the code to:

```
Simplify[(5 + 1/(z-a)) / ( 8 + 1/(z-a))] /. a -> z
```

I got the correct output `1`. Why is that? And how should I deal with expressions involving ∞/∞ ?

Comment: In the first block, when you run `f[a]`, aren't you evaluating `1/(z-a)` where `z = a`, which evaluates to `1/(z-z)` = `undefined`?

Comment: Did you look at the output from `Simplify`? Try `FullSimplify`;the result is enlightening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually:

```
Limit[(5 + 1/(z - a))/(8 + 1/(z - a)), z -> a]
(*
-> 1
*)
```

**Edit**

You may also add a `Direction` option to take the limit coming from either side if necessary:

```
Limit[(5 + 1/(z - a))/(8 + 1/(z - a)), z -> a, Direction -> 1]
```

or

```
Limit[(5 + 1/(z - a))/(8 + 1/(z - a)), z -> a, Direction -> -1]
```

**Edit 2**

The weird behavior of **Simplify[ ]** (allowing some mathematically indefinite expressions to evaluate) is well documented in the help:

[image]

Comment: I think it's that Mathematica doesn't compute an expression as a whole unit, but compute every bit of it, and if any of the bits is not determined by its own, it upload the `Indetermine` value to all its ancestors. And if you want Mathematica to do more intellectual thinking on an expression, you have to tell it what exactly you need.

Comment: @trVoldemort, only to a limited extent. If your numerator and denominator were evaluated separately, i.e. in different functions, then it would be true. But, it can often anticipate such errors, particularly when dealing with numerical values. Try `f[10^-10 + a]` to see what I mean. However, it can't perform the same set of optimizations in symbolic calculations, which `f[a]` is.

Answer (score 3):

No, ∞/∞ is undefined. Consider that 2 ( ∞/∞ ) = (2∞/∞) = ∞/∞, which could be massaged to make 1 = 2 if ∞/∞ were defined as 1.

Comment: Note that L'Hopital's rule only applies to limits. It's entirely possible for a function to have two different limits as you approach a singularity from different directions. (Simple case: 1/x approaches +∞ from the positive side of 0, and -∞ from the negative side.)

Comment: I know sometimes ∞/∞ is undetermined, but in this particular case, you can see that f[a] is definitly `1`.

Comment: @trVoldemort, no it is not. Only the limit of `f` as `z` goes to `a` equals 1. Out of convenience, we tend to set a function equal to the limit at that value because it is true for continuous functions. But, infinity is not a number, and at best you can say that as `|z-a|` becomes small, `f[z]` approaches 1. (Which is the definition of a limit.) So, Mathematica is absolutely correct when it chokes on this.

Answer (score 2):

Infinity is not a number, so operations with it are pointless if you treat it as one:

```
infinity + 1 = infinity
(infinity + 1) - infinity = infinity - infinity
1 = 0
```

Other than that, limits are not always equal to the function's value, which is what Mathematica is hinting at when it gives you the error.

Answer (score 1):

Infinity is not necessarily equal to infinity. Therefore, you cannot make the assertion that "infinity/infinity = 1".

Comment: True, Inf/n = Inf for any n, but n/Inf = 0 for any n.

Comment: You can't perform operations with infinity. It just doesn't make sense, as infinity doesn't exist. It's intangible. You can't mix countable and uncountable objects together and expect sane results. You're hinting at *limits*, as the *limit* of `x / n` as `x -> inf` is `inf`. You can't treat infinity as a number, because it isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

Dividing infinity by infinity is indeed indeterminate. Taking the limit of `f(x)/g(x)` where `f` and `g` tend to infinity might produce an actual limit (or it might not). In your case the limit happens to be 1.